# React storybook - Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook

I am trying to create react story book for table. But I am getting this error when I run yarn run storybook, tried importing css-loader as well, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

````
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @use '../../shared/styles/Variable.module.scss' as font;```
````

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue:

Run yarn add -D @storybook/preset-scss css-loader sass-loader style-loader

Add below addon in .storybook/main.ts

addons: [
'@storybook/preset-scss'
],